# How do I pass filenames with spaces in them to `zip`?

Tags: zsh, zip, escape-characters

This feels like an incredibly simple task, but I can't get it to work. I want to put the first 13 files in a directory into a `.zip` archive. The obvious way to do this is

```
    zip first13.zip $(ls | head -n 13)
```

But this fails because some of the filenames--which I can't change for stupid institutional reasons--have spaces in them. Replacing `ls` with `ls --quoting-style=shell-always` doesn't help (it actually makes things worse, because somehow `zip` ends up looking for files that start and end with literal `'` characters, and yet still parses the spaces...) and neither does

```
    ls | head -n 13 | xargs zip first13.zip
```

Again, `zip` parses the spaces.

Weirdly, `zip all.zip ./*` works fine, so clearly *some* kind of escaping is possible, but I don't know how to replicate whatever `zsh` does in its globbing.

In case there is more than one version of `zip` out there, mine is the one that comes in Arch Linux's official `zip` package, and identifies itself as `Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP`. The shell is `zsh` version 5.8.

Comment: No, this is not the obvious way to do this, [`ls` should be avoided to be parsed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `zsh`, you should be able to use a *glob qualifier* of the form `[m,n]` to select a range of matches - avoiding the `head` pipeline (and its implicit whitespace splitting) altogether:

```
zip first13.zip ./*([1,13])
```

See `man zshexpn` for further details